# Binary tree postorder traversal using contiguous implementation

Tags: python, binary-tree

I'm trying to do a binary tree postorder traversal using only contiguous implementation. This is what I've got. But for some reason pos won't update, therefore, the values would only store at index 0 of the contiguous array. The result I got is only the last value of the traversal, instead of the full completed array of values.

```
INFINITY = 100


def postorder(self):
    contig = Contiguous(INFINITY)
    postorder_helper(self, self.root(),contig)
    return contig


def postorder_helper(bt, node, lst):
    pos = 0
    if node == None or bt.value(node) == None:
        return 
    postorder_helper(bt, bt.left_child(node),lst)
    postorder_helper(bt, bt.right_child(node),lst)
    lst.store(pos, bt.value(node))  ## store(index, value) takes a value and store it in array at given index
    pos = pos + 1
# ie. Expected(8, 14, 5, 13, 16)
# returned (16)
```

Comment: `pos` is a local variable.  Each invocation of `postorder` gets its own copy.  Once it returns, that copy goes out of scope and its value is lost.  The final update of `pos` therefore serves no purpose, and you're always passing `0` for `pos` when calling `lst.store`.

Comment: yes thanks, I've noticed that. Are there anyways I can fix this problem? I tried writing the update at different locations but none of them seemed to be working.

Comment: If you need to keep track of the position, then one way is to pass it as a parameter to `postorder_helper`, and have it return the new position.

Comment: If you're appending the values to the list, then you could just use the list length to get the position.

Comment: by writing len(lst) at where pos is in store? If i still want to keep track of position with pos instead, would i need to set pos = 0 in the parameter and leave the update at the last row?